# How do i get a kniematic body to collide with my tilemap?

Tags: godot

My kinematic body does not sense collision with my tilemap.  Ive defined collision for the tilemap via the drag and drop collision boxes in the tileset.  I dont know what could be the issue.

KinematicBody2D

```
extends KinematicBody2D

export var max_speed = 48
export var min_speed = 16
export var acceleration = 4
var speed = min_speed

# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _ready():
    pass

# Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous frame.
func _physics_process(delta):
    var velocity = Vector2()
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_up"):
        velocity.y -= 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
        velocity.x -= 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_down"):
        velocity.y += 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
        velocity.x += 1
    if Input.is_key_pressed(KEY_Q):
        speed += acceleration
        speed = clamp(speed,min_speed,max_speed)
    else:
        speed -= acceleration
        speed = clamp(speed,min_speed,max_speed)
    if velocity.length() > 0:
        velocity = velocity.normalized() * speed
    var collision = self.move_and_collide(velocity * delta)
    if collision:
        print_debug("collision")
```

https://github.com/MonkeyToiletLadder/godotTilemap
I'm hoping someone can download my project settings and see what the issue is. Id be happy if i got a working example from someone.  Thank you.

Comment: Try enabling "Visible Collision Shapes" in the Debug menu before starting the project, so you can see whether collision shapes were actually added to the scene or not.

Comment: Thank you.  Turning on visible collision bodies helped me find the issue.  My player was at the top left of my screen.  Not within the bounds of the level but my camera was centered on the middle of the level.  So the player was colliding i just couldn't see it.